# How to read Excel data from C++ project

Tags: c++, excel

I my c++ project I want to open an excel file and query data and identify the rows that matches the specific column values(more than one column). What is the best methodology to connect to excel and query the worksheets?

The excel might contain several thousands of records and hence it is very important to complete the search and show the results in quick time and optimum performance.

Request you to let me know more than one option and suggest the best out of it.

Comment: vtc - this question is off-topic for this site as is it asking for recommendations rather than a specific programming problem that can be replicated.

Answer (score 0):

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2879322/444255) for a library (under an open CPOL) license another Stackoverflow user recommends:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2879322/444255